# Project layout for single-page app built using Clojurescript and React

Tags: clojurescript, singlepage, reactjs

I want to build a single-page web application using Clojurescript and React (via Om) and I wonder how to lay out the directory structure for such a project? The project will not contain any backend code. So far, I envisaged the following layout:

```
/[app name]
           /assets
                  /css
                  /js
                  /cljs
                  /...
           /src
                  /[module 1]
                             /view1.cljs
                             /view2.cljs
           /templates
                     /layouts/
                              layout1.html
                     /[module 1]/
                                 view1.html
                                 view2.html
           /test
                /[module 1]
                           /test_view1.cljs
                           /test_view2.cljs
           /doc
               /src
                   /index.rst
               /build
           README.md
```

Is there an established "*standard layout*" for such a project, comparable to the layout imposed by frameworks like Rails, Django or the like?

Comment: that's purely a matter of opinion.

Comment: I'll have to disagree here, since frameworks like Django, Rails, Flask etc. usually impose a pretty strict default directory structure for their projects, so I'm interested to know if such a standard exists for Clojurescript/React projects. I rephrased my question accordingly.

Comment: What is wrong with the structure `lein` gives you?

Comment: As far as I understand `lein` is not specifically tailored to Clojurescript projects, or is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good, but you should have a resources / public and there index.html, etc. templates and unparsed CSS could to in resources with a gruntfile that could parse them into the public folder ( that's the one the server should serve).

**Edit:**  Added an example

```
/[app name]
  src/
    cljs/
      [app_name]/
        core.cljs
    clj/
  test/
  doc/
    index.srt
  resources/
    css/
      index.less
    templates/
      layouts/
        default.jade
      index.jade
    Gruntfile.js
    public/ ; Here grunt and cljsbuild will compile all the resources ->
      index.html
      js/
      cljs/
      css/
        index.css
```

Server should point to `resources/public/` to serve the files

Comment: OK thanks, so would *resources* have to be different from *assets*?

Comment: If assets are the files included by the HTML then they would go inside resources/public/assets... A (maybe) more common way of structuring that would be public/js for js, public/css for CSS, public/img for images, or all slightly longer; public/scripts public/stylesheets and public/images. All of these in resources.

Comment: I added an example in the answer